# not possible to index

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

When running next part of code I have following error:

```
for record in training_data_list:
        all_values = record.split(',')
        y_inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[0]))

        Max = np.zeros(10)
        Max[int(all_values[0])] = 1

        A = A[Max[int(all_values[0])]]
```

The error is:

```
 # print("index=" + str(Max[int(all_values[0])])

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

When running the code:

```
for record in training_data_list:
        all_values = record.split(',')
        y_inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[0]))

        Max = np.zeros(10)
        Max[int(all_values[0])] = 1

        A = A[int(Max[int(all_values[0])])]
```

The error is:

```
---> 22         A = A[int(Max[int(all_values[0])])]
     23 
     24        # print("index=" + str(Max[int(all_values[0])])

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Does somebody know how to use `Max[int(all_values[0])]` as an index?

The shape of A is (10,103)

When writing code like eg:

```
for j in range (0, 9):
    print("A index j =" + str(A[j]))
```

My values for A index j are printed. So why is it not working as in my code above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either `int(all_values[0])` isn't a valid index or `Max[int(all_values[0])]` isn't a valid index. Print these two to see what exactly it is you're referencing.

Comment: 'Max = np.zeros(10)'
'Max[int(all_values[0])] = 1'

'Max = array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])'

Possible values for all_values[0] is (0,1,2, ...,9)
So when all_values[0] = 5 then Max = array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

So therefor I conclude Max[int(all_values[0])] in this example = 5 

So when continue I thought I could use Max[int(all_values[0])] as an index (5 in this case)!
Is there something wrong with the logic?

Comment: By taking a clooser look I think I have only to write A = A[int(all_values[0])